# sending file (soap response) to browser instead of saving on server

Tags: php, file, browser, soap-client

Hi i created a php script that sends a soaprequest to a soapserver. The soapserver makes a file that i want to get back.

I can create the file but so far i need to save it on the server.

Here an example of my code:

```
//  creating some variables for the files i receive from the soap server
$timeStamp  = Time();
$msgFile        .= 'hpoutput/'. $timeStamp . '_messageFile.txt';
$dlfFile        .= 'hpoutput/'. $timeStamp . '_'. $array["return"]["files"]["fileName"];

// saving the messagefile to the server
$var_str    = var_export($array["return"]["engineMessage"], true);
file_put_contents($msgFile, $var_str);

// saving the actual output file to the server 
$var_str    = serialize($array["return"]["files"]["fileOutput"]);
file_put_contents($dlfFile, $var_str);
```

Questions:
- Can i send the created file directly to the browser, without saving it on the server?
- If this isn't possible, how can i remove (clean up) my temp space?

Comment: What do you mean sending it to directly to the browser?

Comment: I get the base64 encoded document in an array value in the soap response. I would like to decode and directly present the document instead of decode, saving it on the server and presenting a link to open it.

Comment: What is th type of the file you are getting?
Is it an image, a text file...?

Comment: It is a dlf file (Dialogue Layout Format) that's a document format from HP. But the problem will be the same with a pdf file.

Comment: You can decode the file, set the proper headers, and echo the content, follow by a die. That will cause the user to download the file.